# warning: ‘s’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc

Basically at the most basic level I cant understand why can't I do this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mal(char *str){
    str = malloc(sizeof(char));
}



int main(void)
{
    char *s;
    mal(s);
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: because `str` inside `mal()` and `s` inside `main()` are different objects. Any change to `str` is **not** reflected in `s` (in other words: C passes arguments by value).

Comment: Note that allocating a single character means the result can only ever (legitimately ) store one string — the empty string.

Comment: The most basic level is that you do not understand how C function arguments and parameters work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`s` gets passed by value to the function `mal`. Inside `mal` the local parameter `str` gets changed by the assignment, but `s` in `main` is kept uninitialized. In C you should pass a pointer to `s` to `mal` to resolve this problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void mal(char **str){ // pointer to pointer
    *str = malloc(sizeof(char)); // referenced variable behind str changed
}



int main(void)
{
    char *s;
    mal(&s); // pointer to s passed
    free(s);
    return 0;
}
```